# Any SQL strip function available

Tags: sql, string, db2

I am trying to run an update query which will strip `-` from a field.  For example:

```
ID   NAME
------------
1    you-me
```

On updating, I want to strip the "-".  The result should be:

```
ID   NAME
------------
1    youme
```

Is there any sql command to do this?  I am using DB2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight REPLACE function then?

```
update tbl set col = REPLACE(col, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use SQL `REPLACE` function

```
UPDATE table
SET column = REPLACE(column, '-', '');
```

See [this documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_bif_replace.htm)

Comment: +1 for DB2 doco link, but `in future`, please don't post answers 14 minutes after an exact duplicate has already been posted